# Xcode Frameworks folder class reference not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, frameworks

I am trying to add ads into my Swift 3 SpriteKit game. Specifically, AdColony and Vungle. The problem is that when I import the frameworks that they supply me, nothing works. For Example:

[image]

Now when I add a bridge Objective-C file and `#import <VungleSDK/VungleSDK.h>` like I was told, I get an error reading: `VSwift-Bridging-Header.m:9:9: 'VungleSDK/VungleSDK.h' file not found`. I have tried moving the folder `VungleSDK/VungleSDK.h` but that still did nothing.

Now with AdColony I have imported that but the bridge file is fine. When I try and reference a class in my `.swift` files from the AdColony frameworks folder it reads: `GameOverScene.swift:47:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'AdColony'`. I have read/did the AdColony/Vungle tutorials (Vungle: https://v.vungle.com/dashboard/applications/5942ea1625cbbb8e4f002a70/details AdColony: https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK-3/wiki/Xcode-Project-Setup#adding-the-framework-to-your-xcode-project) but I can't seem to figure out what is the problem and why I am unable to reference anything. I have also downloaded and ran the test projects by both ad services, and they worked just fine.

Comment: VungleSDK.embeddedframework "folder" image looks different. It won't be indicating it as a framework. Find the right path of your header file first.

Comment: @Satyam I agree it does look different, I have tried moving the "VungleSDK.frameworks" folder out and allowing it to be by itself with its children but it still seems to not work.

Comment: how did you get that framework? Did you build it or some one shared it or downloaded from some website?

Comment: @Satyam https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204472160-Get-Started-with-Vungle-iOS-SDK-Swift- I got it from the ad service itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well open the sprite kit then vungle the bundle to the zpode file. Theres two mxRtc's in youre collided folder. Copy one to the gstate.ll and the other to LLcx_z.ff